# nmcli shows disconnected but network is working, many other doubts

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, networkmanager, nmcli, netplan

This is ubuntu 20.04.

I am trying to prep it for VM hosting and I have 4 onboard eth ports and 6 more on PCI cards. But I am new to NM / nmcli and having hard time to figure this out.

nmcli shows nothing but i am able to ssh into the box just fine. "ip a" shows intfc has address from DHCP (using DHCP for testing).

Also I am not sure why does it show wifi enabled. There is no wifi card on the server!!

```
oot@myhost:~# nmcli g
STATE         CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN
disconnected  unknown       enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
root@myhost:~#
root@myhost:~# nmcli device status
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
eno1        ethernet  unmanaged  --
eno2        ethernet  unmanaged  --
eno3        ethernet  unmanaged  --
eno4        ethernet  unmanaged  --
enp129s0f0  ethernet  unmanaged  --
enp129s0f1  ethernet  unmanaged  --
enp131s0f0  ethernet  unmanaged  --
enp131s0f1  ethernet  unmanaged  --
enp3s0f0    ethernet  unmanaged  --
enp3s0f1    ethernet  unmanaged  --
idrac       ethernet  unmanaged  --
lo          loopback  unmanaged  --
root@myhost:~#


root@myhost:~# cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

intfcs have address assigned:

```
root@myhost:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:x:xx:xx:x:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xx.xx.xx.85/24 brd xx.xx.179.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 28169sec preferred_lft 28169sec
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:x:xx:x:xx:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:x:x:x:x:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp3s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:x:x:x:x:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: enp129s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:x:x:x:x:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:x:x:x:f2:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: enp3s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:x:x:x:x:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: enp129s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:x:x:x:1d:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: enp131s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:x:x:x:x:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: enp131s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:x:x:x:x:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: idrac: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:x:x:x:x:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

It seems this file is responsible for bringing up the network: If I use networkmanager can i remove this file? It seems it dosent matter what utiltiy (NM or networkd) you use this file has to used.....

```
# cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

question:

1. if network is being configured and working fine WITHOUT networkManager utility. Then why do I need this?
2. but if, that netplan thing is doing the job then can I not just use it (How???) to take care of all network configuration work?
3. So, if netplan is a *poor joke* then, how to make things look 'normal' in nmcli?
4. I am ultimately wanting to:
   4.1) host VMs on this server.
   4.2) pass thru PCI eth ports directly to VMs.

(I was very upset to find out that cockpit does not work with networkd, so i HAD to stick to nmcli.)
finally, where are nmcli config files and are they per interface? and do the changes persist after reboot?

Thank you.

Comment: perhaps [this documentation](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/networkmanager-and-netplan) explains it?

Comment: `where are nmcli config files` - it doesn't matter, since if you use netplan = *During early boot netplan generates backend specific configuration files in /run to hand off control of devices to a particular networking daemon* - i.e. `netplan` does not control networking devices at all, it's a front end to either networkd or NetwrokManager

Comment: thank you. i think it is a third rate setup from ubuntu. I figured that nmcli config is in /etc/NEtworkManager... and one should add renderer entry in netplan config. and then forget about netplan - garbage. if ubuntu system is not clearly being managed by either nm or networkd then it is one big s.h.i.t. situation....

Comment: another thing i found out setting up KVM on ubuntu is : NM and libvirt both have 3 different places where config is found /etc/... /var/.... and /usr/... just some more garbage software from ubuntu.

Comment: the location of NetworkManager and libvirt config files have naff all to do with ubuntu. It's just how things are in Unix/Linux. Consider the alternative operating systems, they are not any better, with their registries, and multiple folders for config data - computing isn't simple like basket weaving